# Is it possible to update a value contained in an object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, javascript-objects

My data base actually looks like that :

```
{
  object1: {
    object2: {
      enabled: false,
      string: "foo"
    },
    object3: {
      enabled: true,
      string: "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

I wanna update the `enabled:` of the `object2` without changing the `"foo"` value.

I tried this:

```
data.updateOne({ object1: { object2: { enabled: true } } });
```

but it change all the `object2`, it delete the `object3` and delete the `string` value of the `object2`.
How can i update my database without change it totally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [the dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set):

> To specify a < field > in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.

```
data.updateOne({ query }, { $set: { "object1.object2.enabled": true } });
```